# When I try to run SmbClient command to copy image under one folder to another folder over server using Java Process it is giving FileNotFound

Tags: java

I wanted to copy 100k images(90 GB) from one folder to another folder in server using SMBClient in Java. So tried one file(index.xlsx) first, but I am getting the following error

Source location : //naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/Sai/testPay/index.xlsx

Targetr location : //naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/Sai/job/index.xlsx
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "smbclient": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)

Following is the program

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(
        "smbclient Image2 "
        + "-L naiy83e00txe2 -M naiy83e00txe2 -W RTX1 -U PaySupport -c "
        + "\"put //naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/Sai/testPay/index.xlsx //naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/Sai/job/index.xlsx\" -m SMB2");
    
    String dest = str.toString();
    System.out.println("Smbclinet command:" + dest);
      try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dest);
  
        int waitFor = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(waitFor);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Actually I was using jcifs.smb.SmbFile copyTo method in forEach stream to do this but it was taking more than 3 days to copy 100k images, moreover it is getting truncated in the middle.

So thought of runninng SMbclient command instead of jcifs.smbfile.copyTO, but I was getting above error.

Can somebody help me with these Smbcommands to run with ProcessBuilder in java to achieve 100kImages copied faster?

Comment: use absolute path to smbclient.

Comment: Sorry din't get, you mean /usr/bin/smbclient?

Comment: for example, yes

Comment: ```-L``` ? That's a listing command is it not? Does that command actually work at the command line?

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work. Moreover when we deploy the code on servers, we would not have smbclient and absolute path

Comment: @goose tried to install SmbClient on command line to check this but don't have permissions to install, downloaded samba-4.16.4 tar file and extracted but can't move further

Comment: *Tried that, but didn't work. Moreover when we deploy the code on servers, we would not have smbclient and absolute path*. Baffling. How do you hope to execute smbclient if it's not even installed?

Comment: Is there any other way to make more than 100k images of more than 90GB to copy faster from one folder to another folder through java in remote server? currently it's working using jcifs.smb.SmbFile .copyTo method inside forEach but it is taking more than 2 days to copy

Comment: It might be worth posting that code - there could be something wrong with it

Comment: @g00se private void copy(List<String> fileList) {
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(nasDomain, nasUsername, nasPassword);
fileList.parallelStream().forEach((filepath) -> {
   String sourcePath = new StringBuilder("//naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/").append("Sai/testPay/").append(filepath)
     .toString();
   String targetPath = new StringBuilder("//naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/").append("Sai/job/").toString();
   try {
    SmbFile targetSMBPath = new SmbFile("smb:" + targetPath, auth);
    if (!targetSMBPath.exists()) {
     targetSMBPath.mkdir();
    }

Comment: SmbFile imageSMBpath = new SmbFile("smb:" + actualPathToSearch, auth);
destPathToSearch = new StringBuilder("//naiy83e00txe2/Pay_NP/").append("Sai/job/").append(filepath).toString(); SmbFile destSMBPathFile = new SmbFile("smb:" + destPathToSearch, auth);
    if (!targetSMBPath.exists()) {
     imageSMBpath.copyTo(targetSMBPath);
    }
   } catch (MalformedURLException | SmbException e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
   }
  });
}

Comment: I think it would be better for you to delete those comments and put the code in your actual question

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong there. I was looking for repeated authentication but fortunately that's absent. I don't know JCIFS but afaik it's a very professional thing. My best guess is that the 'default' environment settings in it are different from smbclient. You might need to dig into the API docs more. Maybe stuff like default copy buffer sizes(?) And, if they've got logging right, you ought to be able to turn on log debug for the API and find out something about bottlenecks. Of course a JCIFS user group could be informative